# Unauthorized: authentication required Harbor

Tags: docker, harbor, docker-cli

I am facing the following issue.

I have a harbor private registry and i am trying to login through docker cli.

I am able to login successfully with: `docker login <harbor_ip>`. When i execute this command the cli is asking me for username and password and it logins successfully.

But when i try to login with the following command `docker login -u <username> -p <password> <harbor_ip>` i get the following error:

```
unauthorized: authentication required
```

Bear in mind i am using the same credentials.

Why this is happening?

Comment: Any special characters in your password that might break password input? Have you tried using the long notation instead of shorthand (-u and -p)? Are you absolutely sure the input is the same? What happens if you put the password in a file and use --password-stdin?

Answer (score 3):

Please wrap your username and password with single quote

```
docker login -u '<username>' -p '<password>' <harbor_ip>
```

Comment: I find it INSANE that this was the fix for me. This is such a glaring defect in the CLI IMO.

Answer (score 0):

when you are using haproxy or cdn infront of harbor to handle ssh termination, its important to set external_url in harbor.yml file.

it solved my problem